# Why are my net names not corectly exported to a SPICE netlist?

Tags: spice, kicad

I have a schematic:

[image: schematic]

When I export this with the "Export Netlist" feature...

[image: netlist dialog]

The SPICE netlist has renamed my `Hello` and `World` nets to `NC_01` and `NC_02`...

```
.title KiCad schematic
F1 HelloWorld NC_01 Net-_F1-Pad3_ FET
R1 VDD HelloWorld 10Meg
F2 Net-_F1-Pad3_ NC_02 GND FET
.end
```

What am I doing wrong to make KiCad ignore the net names?

Comment: I tried adding labels (non-global) to the nets also; no affect. My guess is, nothing is wrong; the labels simply are not exported at this time. Sounds like a good feature request.

Answer (score 5):

Well net labels are exported if there is a net (see the helloworld label). You will need to have something connected to the pins with your labels otherwise there is nothing that uses your labels.

Comment: Whereas the HelloWorld tag carries over because R1 and F1 are connected to it. It's not just floating.

Comment: This works - when driven by a voltage source the net names are correctly exported. I'll add this as a feature request though, as there is no reason these nets shouldn't be exported